# how to puppet and diff without fqdn?

Tags: deployment, puppet, openstack, facter, mcollective

I have one problem, that how to manage the agent-nodes with puppet?

I'm using the openstack to auto generating the vms, and then puppet with several puppet-code in special pattern.

eg.

The system provision several vms, each vm has two attrs:

> `fqdn`: maybe repeat(you know the vms are genrate by system in a complex env)
>
> `uuid`: this will be unique, and is stored in a persistent file. it won't change

and below are two of them.

VM1:

```
fqdn: api-server.expamle.com
uuid: 20a558f1-2cd9-4068-b5fc-8d252c3f3262
```

VM2:

```
fqdn: api-server.expamle.com
uuid: 096359d6-5dc9-47e9-946a-bd702fe7c2d5
```

(Also, I can specify the hostname with the `uuid`, but I think it's not a good idea.)

and now I want to puppet them with `puppet kick` or `mcollective puppet runonce`.

with `mco`, i can choose the facter uuid, that will diff VM1&VM2.

`mco pupppetd runonce --with-facter uuid=20a558f1-2cd9-4068-b5fc-8d252c3f3262`

but I STILL MUST hardcode the fqdn in the puppet-code

```
node api-server.expamle.com {
    ...
}
```

but in fact, I just want use it in the following style:

```
facter 20a558f1-2cd9-4068-b5fc-8d252c3f3262 {
    ...
}
facter 096359d6-5dc9-47e9-946a-bd702fe7c2d5 {
    ...
}
```

how can I write the puppet? or do some change in the architecture?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of assigning roles/classifying a node in puppet.

A solution closer to the example you provided would be to use the following node.pp file

```
node default {

  case $::uuid {
    "20a558f1-2cd9-4068-b5fc-8d252c3f3262": {
        include apache
        ...
    }
    "096359d6-5dc9-47e9-946a-bd702fe7c2d5": {
        include ngnix
        ...
    }
    default: {
        ...
    }
  }

}
```

Saying that, I am not sure that this is the best solution. There are better ways assigning classes/roles to a node.

I would suggest to look at puppet hiera (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html) or ENC (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) for better mechanisms.

Comment: thx, this does help for me.  i did changed the fqdn to the uuid in the image, but this provide another way. thank you